# multiple databases - common connection pool using pgbouncer

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

We have a multi tenant set up with one database for each tenant in a single server. Is it possible to main a common pool for all databases with pgbouncer? Our number databases in one server can range in a few hundreds. While I can have a large number of connections from application to pgbouncer, I am limited by the number of connection I can have with postgres server. What is the best approach in this scenario?

Comment: in what way are you limited by the number of connections to the postgres server?

Comment: thanks for your response. There is max connection setting in pg_hba conf, and each connection takes huge memory - roughly about 4 mb.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to setup pgBouncer to have same connection pooling settings for all databases ?

Comment: Hello. What approach have you finally chosen in the end? I have similar situation, and also hit connection limits of postgres. One solution I see is to create schema per tenant, not database. But it seems there will be some drawbacks with backups, logging, etc.

Comment: According to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36724/does-pgbouncer-create-a-separate-pool-for-every-database-config-entry it does not seem to be the case.